# Unable to get data out of datatask completion handler in objective c

Tags: objective-c, json, nsurlsessiondatatask

I am trying to get data through JSON approach using nsurlsessiondatatask but I am unable to get the data out of the data task completion handler.

Please help????

Answer (score 0):

NSURLSessionDataTask has a method called resume. Make sure you call it after you create your data task object.

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""] completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", response);
}];
[task resume];
```

Comment: yes I did called but data inside completion handler iam unable to use.

Comment: NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
 for(int i=0;i<=10;i++){
 NSString *date =  [[[json objectForKey:@"response"]objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"date"];
 NSLog(@"Date Content : %@",date);
 self.dayDate = [date substringToIndex:2];
  NSLog(@"day date content is %@",self.dayDate);
  self.dateAdder=self.dayDate;
  NSLog(@"date Adder : %@",self.dateAdder);
                                         
                                     }
    NSLog(@"date Adder Before datatask : %@",self.dateAdder);
    [dataTask resume];

Comment: @AkashIOS, can you post the format of the json data that you get from remote call?

Comment: I am getting the data in the form of nsdictionary which is perfectly fine but the main problem iam getting is data is becoming nil at first instance as I am supposed to use this data in didselectrowatindex tableview delegate method.

Comment: Have you declared property dateAdder strong?